# For pivot_root I want to kill all processes oldroot is using so that I can detach MTD partition.. and exit shell and go back in

Tags: linux, bash, shell, chroot

I have an embedded linux on arm7.

I have a rootfs mounted on MTD partition 10 (for example), i.e. /dev/mtd10, which is a flash device. The volume is UBIFS device UBI0 (/dev/ubi0).

I have setup a pivot_root (similar to a chroot) tmpfs roughly following the instructions from here: [resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto](http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml).

I want to erase/re-format mtd10 (UBI0) The problem that I have is that I can't detach/format UBI0 until I have because it tells me its busy. So, I use the command:

`fuser -vm /dev/mtd10` and this gives me a list of processes that I can kill, so I do all that and then umount (or umount -l) all the partitions that are mounted on UBI0.

So my system no longer has any dependency on UBI0... except the shell I am running. I have tried combinations of many things, but the only thing that seems to work (once I have tidied up) is to logout (using `exit` command) and then log back in (for me I just have to type in the username `root`).

As soon as I logout/run `telinit u` at this point then I see the UBI0 go away and I can detatch it.

**update:** killing `rc_mxc.S` has a similar effect to loging out (i.e. it ends my shell and I have to login again. But this also ends my script :(

The problem here is that I don't know how I can script that up. Running `exit` in a script just ends the script.

Comment: Have you ensured the current directory for your shell is not on the device? Or the file holding the shell binary (say /bin/sh), or the file holding the shell script is on the device? You can do something like `exec /tmp/.../bin/sh /tmp/.../myscript` to swap over to a new shell script, releasing some of these.

Comment: @meuh hmm... I think it is somthing to do with that. As I say if I kill my shell or logout (both have a similar effect) then I can free the device. I was actually just messing around with running a script `exec myscript.sh` to kill of everything including the `sh` that was running on the device and that seemed to work (but after the script I still need to login again) - however I think because my `sh` that I start in is on the device then the exec may also be on it so I had to not terminate the `sh` that I spawned ...complicated! - in short, I will try your recommendation as it seems sound :)

Comment: What about using initramfs that never "pivots" to a "physical" file system?

Comment: @jc__ that looks really like what I want to do!...but I can't find a simple/basic example of this. It seems like you build up a tmp-rootfs similar to creating a chroot/pivot_root folder (in RAM/tmpfs) - but then I am not sure what happens... Do you need to have a specific init script... bit confused as how exactly initramfs work - if you have any good links or want to layout an answer I'll happily mark them up :)

Comment: Are you just needing to do maintenance on your system (partition,format)? If yes boot to a live distro (via USB). If you want to create a custom 'distro', that will consist of building a kernel from source and using something like busybox for a simple init. Buildroot for a custom 'distro' that is more advanced. What boot loader are you using? uboot? uboot contains tools to partition and format too. I said all that to ask: What is your ultimate goal? What do you need to accomplish?

Comment: lol, yeah I get where you are coming from!. We have uboot, but what I want is a bunch of apps running. Then at some point the user may pass in a software suit containing new apps, kernel, rootfs etc... At that point I want to install the new kernel, rootfs, apps etc... but I also want to try to keep the ssh (or whatever ip) connection alive while its happening .    Normal mode of operation is that we have a rootfs on the flash device... so may normal operation really ought to be initramfs?...that is what I am thinking - but I wanted to try-before-I buy buy switch_root'ing over....so somthing

Answer (score 0):

Run `find /proc/$$ -type l -ls` in the shell that's holding the FS open. For each one of those links that points to that FS, take appropriate action:

- In the `fd` subdirectory: run `exec n>replacement`, where `n` is the file descriptor number and `replacement` is the file it should point at, or `&-` to close that descriptor.
- As `exe` or in the `map_files` subdirectory: run `exec /bin/sh`, replacing `/bin/sh` with the path to any shell you want in your tmpfs root.
- As `cwd`: `cd` to some other directory.
- As `root`: go to the tmpfs root, and `chroot .`.

Comment: hm... sorry, I really don't get what this is trying to do + did not work : (